# Draw custom graph python

Tags: python

I am trying to draw a graph but on specific conditions like:

1. Value on odd array index **up**, value on even array index **down** (in short one time up, second time down and continue like this)
2. length of dashed line should be equal to value on index

on

```
list = [3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,2,2,4,1,2,4,5,5,1,3,2,2]
```

length of dashed **line going up** should be `3 dashes`, then length of **line going down** should be `4 dashes`

I just need libraries which is customizable for this and syntaxes to achieve this, or may be just share anything

[image: Graph pic]

Comment: Hi Dahaar, what have you tried since now to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) or OpenGL.

> Turtle graphics is a popular way for introducing programming to kids. It was part of the original Logo programming language developed by Wally Feurzeig, Seymour Papert and Cynthia Solomon in 1967.